# How to get order total without discount Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I load an order model like this:

```
$order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);
```

and to get the order total i use :

```
$order->getGrandTotal();
```

this order total will show the total order with discount included, how can i get the order total without discount from coupon code and any special price included?

Comment: Is it working? @blue

Comment: use $order->getSubtotal(); instead of grand total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this below code :

```
$order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
$itemQty = array();
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
     $itemQty['price'] = $item->getPrice();
}
return $itemQty;
```

Comment: are there no other simple way?

Comment: Is it not working? It's proper magento standard way.

Comment: Please accept and upvote answer if it's working. So, this will be useful for other developers.

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :)